# Javascript hide HTML text if input box is not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form where users are able to input their mobile number. See below:

```
<form class="formulario" action="signature_test.html" method="get" onsubmit="return signature_Alert()" >
        Mobile (mgrs):  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate Signature">
</form>
```

Whatever the user enters, is then populated in another HTML file. It innerHTML the text "Default":

```
<font color="#008080">Mobile: </font></b><font id="mobileInput">Default </font><br>
```

However, I would like that if the user leaves the mobile field blank, to have the "Mobile:" and the "Default" not displayed. Is that possible with Javascript?

By the way, this would be the Javascript that innerHTML the "Default" text.

```
<script>      
      var values = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&')
      var mobile = values[3].split('=')[1]
      document.getElementById('mobileInput').innerHTML = mobile;
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated, you should use `<span>` with `style` attribute, or use classes.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I tried the following:  <font color="#008080" onload="return Function()">Mobile: </font></b><font id="mobileInput">Default </font><br>. It didn't return the function.

Comment: well in this case according to your example the form just should not be submitted? Or you have more other fields in the form? Anyway, you can just add a condition that if mobileInput value = 'default', then you just hide this entire <span> or <p> (you should change <font> to either of these as per above comment) with setting css visibility to hidden. can draft a code if needed

Comment: what does the variable `mobile` look like when the user doesn't enter a number? You should check for that case and if its empty remove the `mobileInput` tag and add a tag around Mobile and remove it too

Comment: If the user doesn't enter a value. It appears blank: it replaces the "Default" text with blank. But I would also like the "Mobile:" to not appear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just wrap the content in an element you can target and modify:

```
<span id="mobileInputContainer">
    <font color="#008080">Mobile: </font></b><font id="mobileInput">Default </font><br>
</span>
```

Then just adjust that element's style similar to how you already adjust another element's content:

```
if (mobile.length < 1) {
    document.getElementById('mobileInputContainer').style.display = 'none';
}
```

You'd of course want to double-check the actual value you're getting for `mobile` in your code.  Make sure it doesn't have whitespace, etc.  Or really tweak whatever your logic is for *determining* that no value is present to display.  But the actual act of hiding the element is simple, just set the style to be hidden.

Additionally, I'd like to echo [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329039/javascript-hide-html-text-if-input-box-is-not-filled#comment83643782_48329039).  `<font>` tags really shouldn't be used anymore.  You'll find a little bit of an introduction to CSS styling can go a *long* way here.  I recommend some introductory tutorials on the subject.

You also appear to have an errant `</b>` in your code.  Perhaps you're not showing us the entire content.  Either way, you'll want to double-check your HTML as well.  Always start with valid and well-formed HTML before using any JavaScript or CSS, or behavior may not be what you expect.